# Angular 6 Communicating between Parent&Child components using @Output

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 6 project.

I need to communicate between parent and child components(from parent to child) but actually by using @Output I could not achieve this.

Please help me regarding the below codes.

child component:survey.component.html

`<div style="text-align:center">
<app-root (numberGenerated)='selectValue($event)'></app-root>`

survey.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, SkipSelf , Input, Output , EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from '../parent/app.component'

@Component({
selector: 'app-survey',
templateUrl: './survey.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./survey.component.css']
})
export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {

selectValue( newValue : any ) {
 console.log(newValue);
}
constructor(){}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

parent component: app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input , Output , EventEmitter } from    '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'BegumSurvey';

@Output() private numberGenerated = new EventEmitter<number>();

 public generateNumber() {
   const randomNumber = Math.random();
   this.numberGenerated.emit(randomNumber);
 }

 constructor(){
 }
 ngOnInit() {

 }
 }
```

app.component.html

```
<button class="btn" (click)="generateNumber()">Fire event!</button>
```

Could you please help me to understand why even 'Fire event!' is not printed?

Thanks much.

Any help is appreciated.

Begum

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say hi all:)

Comment: That should work, but I'm confused... seems survey component is the parent, and app component is the child. In your question you are saying otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass data from the parent component to the child component, then you need to use @Input decorator alone with property binding. Below is the sample code base on your clarification.

```js
survey-child.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey-child',
  templateUrl: './survey-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey-child.component.css']
})
export class SurveyChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() surveyChildValue: string;
  public testValue: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testValue = this.surveyChildValue;
    this.selectValue();
  }

  selectValue() {
    console.log(this.surveyChildValue);
    
  }

}

survey-parent.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey-parent',
  templateUrl: './survey-parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey-parent.component.css']
})
export class SurveyParentComponent implements OnInit {
  parentValue: string = 'Angular 6 Communicating between Parent&Child components using @Input';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
survey-child.component.html

<!--This will print the Value you assignned in Parnet in UI as we use interpretation -->
<p>
  {{testValue}}
</p>

survey-parent.component.html

<app-survey-child [surveyChildValue]="parentValue"></app-survey-child>




app.component.html
<router-outlet>
  <app-survey-parent></app-survey-parent>

</router-outlet>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKBrX.png)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: However, I have a question that console.log(this.surveyChildValue) is 'undefined'. Could you please help me about the reason. Thanks.

Comment: Did you pass the parentValue in CSS Selector as below.
<app-survey-child [surveyChildValue]="parentValue"></app-survey-child>. Basically parentValue variable is passing to child component  when you declare the selector in Template. Also you have to use the same variable name which is surveyChildValue

Comment: Do I need to use a service?

Comment: Nop. No Service is require. The intention of Services are to make HTTP calls to bring data in from your Rest API. Kindly send me the code. It works find for me and i have attached the screenshot in my Answer .

Comment: Okey thanks for the info :) How will i send you the code? Is there any email?

Comment: I am very new to Angular so as I learned from google that it says: 'You are passing an input in the root component, which will not work.' Yes I was trying to pass a variable from the root component. Is it really the issue?

Comment: Very well be. I usually won't play with app/root component. In app.componenet Template (html file), i'll only give router outlet so routing will take place as per the route definition. I would suggest to create separate components. I'll be able to send you a sample app with Layout and side Nav bar on Mondy if you drop me a message.

Comment: Thanks much:) I will remind you myself. Take care! see you on Monday!

Comment: Hello @Chandana

Comment: Could you please give me address to send you my code that is still not working? Thanks

Comment: unfortunately I can't access my personal emails at work since everything has restricted. Let me see a way to share the code which is working for me.

Comment: I have uploaded sample code in GitHub for your reference. Wiki link:https://github.com/chandanas01/StackExchange/wiki/Step-by-Step:-How-to-create-an-Angular-7-Project-with-Collapsible-Side-Navigation                                                                 code link: https://github.com/chandanas01/Layout-with-Side-Nav-Bar/blob/master/Layout-with-NavBar-Code.zip

Answer (score 0):

> I need to communicate between parent and child components(from parent to child) but actually by using @Output I could not achieve this.

`@Output` is for child-to-parent interaction. What you need is to use `@Input` (parent-to-child interaction):

Parent component(app.ts):

```
this.numberGenerated = Math.random();
```

Parent component(app.html):

```
<app-survey [newValue]="numberGenerated"></app-survey>
```

Child component(survey.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit, SkipSelf , Input, Output, Input, EventEmitter} from 
'@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from '../parent/app.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-survey',
  templateUrl: './survey.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./survey.component.css']
})
export class SurveyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() newValue;
  ...
```

`@Output` is the child's EventEmitter property. More is here: [Angular component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: But according to OP's code, app component is the child here. Says op has in **survey component** the tag: `<app-root (numberGenerated)='selectValue($event)'></app-root>` Therefore I'm confused :D

Comment: @AJT_82 he stated in question that `survey component` is a child of `app component`. But by code, yes, it's like you said. Though the OP's statement `(from parent to child) but actually by using @Output` is not right, because `@Output` is a decorator for child event emitter property.

Comment: Hi both. Thanks for the remark. I am trying to understand the input output components so maybe I wrote it wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

With @Output and EventEmitter it is the other way around. You can pass data back from the child to the parent component. Again in the child, we declare a variable but this time with the@Output decorator and a new EventEmitter