# How to share query param between parent and children routes?

Tags: angular, router

I build a website where the template has been divided to components. The header and footer of the template are in **main.component.html** file and the body is injected with **router-outlet**.

The only part that is changing on navigation is the body. The header and footer stay the same. A storeid query parameter is shared to dynamically build the body.

Where I got a problem is when I have to fetch the storeid query param from the **main.component.ts** file. I don’t know how to do that with my current route configurations.

Here are the routes configurations:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent, // HOME PAGE
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]
  },
    {
    path: '', // I TRIED ':storeid' here but negative
    component: MainLayoutComponent, // MAIN LAYOUT IS DIVIDED AS DESCRIBED IN QUESTION. THIS IS THE STOREID I HAVE TO FETCH FROM HERE
    children: [
      { path: 'event-details/:storeid', component: EventDetailsComponent }, // SO AS HERE TOO.
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'error-404', component: Error404PageComponent },
  { path: 'error-500', component: Error500PageComponent },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

David might be a little late, but I think I have a solution to your problem.

Usually, when working with params, that are passed inside your route, we access those params by injecting the `ActivatedRoute`, after that by subscribing to the exposed `params` observable or by taking the params directly form the current url by using `snapshot.params`.

```js
export class {Your}Component implements OnInit {

  params
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.params = x
      });
     
    this.params =  this.route.snapshot.params
  }
}
```

The tricky part here (which is the question that you are asking) is that by doing this type of access, we can only get the parameters passed in the current route segment.

The easiest solution is to use different [ParamsInheritanceStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#paramsInheritanceStrategy). By setting the inheritance strategy to `always`, you will be able to access params, belonging to the parent routing segments, in the components, attached to child segments. The tricky part when using this strategy is that if you have two params with the same name, they will override, for example, if your route is `store/:storeId/route/:storeId/child` the second `:storeId` will override the previous one if it's called from component related to segment right of the second `:storeId` (`first => second` from left to right ).

You can check a working example here at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qo6s2g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: any performance downsights to setting `ParamsInheritanceStrategy`? Or is it just not activated by default for the above mentioned reason?

Comment: No downsides, the ng router either way aggregates data related to the route params, by using `always` you just overwrite the params, there is a slight chance that is even more performant, but I haven't tested it.
You can check the usage here [Ref To Angular Docs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3c6a439a6fec6c921e08bde583a457953424b4bc/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L218)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass data from the parent component to the child component, then you need to use two things: @Input and property binding.

If you want to pass data back from the child to the parent component, you can use @Output & EventEmitter event binding

Refer below URL as I have answered a related question.
[Angular 6 Communicating between Parent&Child components using @Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067750/angular-6-communicating-between-parentchild-components-using-output/55068483#55068483)

Hope this will be useful to resolve your issue in right way.